# Command Line Copy on Windows XP Embedded

Tags: batch-file, command-line, xcopy, robocopy, windows-embedded

For work I have to write a simple batch file to backup a directory as part of a maintenance routine. The PCs that need to have their directories backed up are running Windows XP Embedded 2002 SP2. These tools do not have the following command line utilities:
-copy
-xcopy.exe
-robocopy.exe

Is there any method of command line copy that is currently on XPe, if not, is there a 3rd party solution and how would I implement this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are these folders going to be backed up to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why, if you can put new files on this machine running an embedded OS, why you wouldn't have just copied xcopy.exe over to it...  Anyway, the program you want and is the best for copying large amounts of files/backups is XXCOPY.  Check out www.xxcopy.com

Comment: I had tried copying xcopy.exe to the machine, but it didn't work. Turns out it was because I copied it from my Windows 7 machine, tried it from an XP machine and it worked. Thank you